# What c++ do for `my_map[i] = my_map.size()`?

Tags: c++

```
std::map<int, int> my_map;
my_map[0] = my_map.size();
```

Then, will `my_map[0]` be `0` or `1`, or undefined?

Comment: why not try it out urself, it is 2 lines of code

Comment: @yngum: You flip a coin, it lands heads up. Does that show that coins land heads up when flipped? The question is about C++ itself, not about a particular compiler, library, or platform.

Comment: Except here the likeliness of the randomness recurring is unlikely. Once it lands heads, it's likely to always land heads for the next while you test it.

Comment: @chris: I don't think so. If it's undefined by the standard, it may well be 0 or 1 based on surrounding code that affects how the line is optimized. Or it may vary based on the selected optimization level. Or some compilers might do it one way and some the other. Each "flip of the coin" may produce a different result based on how the coin was flipped.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, What I mean is that if you compile it and run it, and it shows 1, you could run it ten more times and probably end up with all 1s. Then someone else could compile and run it on their machine ten times and get all 0s.

Comment: @chris: Sure, but I wasn't talking about video taping yourself flipping a coin and watching it several times. I was talking about flipping a coin several times. The process here involves selecting a platform, compiler, and optimization level, compiling this code, running it, looking at the output, and reporting it. That's what yngum was asking someone to do -- not run some code that was already compiled. He was suggesting that someone could easily do this once and answer the question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Ah, I see your point now.

Comment: @updogliu see my edit on my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*There is **no** sequence point here*, so the evaluation order is unspecified (or, in C++11 jargon, the two expressions are *indeterminately sequenced*).
The value of `my_map[0]` is `0` or `1` depending on the implementation.

- [`my_map[0]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5b%5d/) will increase the size if its evaluated first, causing `my_map.size()` to evaluate to `1`. `my_map[0]` will then be `1`.
- However, if `my_map.size()` is evaluated first, then the value for `my_map[0]` will be `0`.

Now, how to make the above behavior *well-defined*? You must introduce a sequence point, that is, force one expression to be sequenced before the other;  for behavior like the first,

```
int& val = my_map[0];
val = my_map.size();
```

... or, for behavior like the second,

```
int sz = my_map.size();
my_map[0] = sz;
```

Make sure to upvote Oo Tiib for being the first to demonstrate how to introduce sequencing for the expressions :-)

Comment: -1 "so the evaluation order is unspecified (or, in C++11 jargon, the two expressions are unsequenced). The value of my_map[0] is 0 or 1 depending on the implementation." - I'd say this actually falls under 1.9.15 "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either anotherside effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.", so it's *undefined behaviour*, not an unspecified choice between 0 and 1. Huge difference.

Comment: The size data member is, and it's modified (a side effect) by insertion at left while a "value computation" is done on it at right.

Comment: @TonyDelroy §3.9.9 "**Arithmetic types (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types (3.9.2), `std::nullptr_-t`, and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called _scalar types_.**" Also, `size` is a member function.

Comment: in a map there is an arithmetic data member (i.e. a scalar) storing the size, I'm not saying the identifier for it is literally "size" - as you say the member function `size()` exists - it trivially returns it.

Comment: @Tony Delroy: Where do you see multiple unsequenced access to *the same* scalar object here, as required by your quote?

Comment: @AndreyT: Nowhere. It is stretched. map::operator[]() may modify size of map and in OP example it certainly does. map::size() accesses it. C++ standard requires map::size() to be O(1) so for that map has likely to keep some member of arithmetic type.

Comment: @Öö Tiib: exactly... it's common sense... I'd say "implied" by - or "deduced" from depending on presepective - the functionality rather than "stretched" - but seems we're speaking of the same concern.

Comment: @AndreyT: (obviously, all this is equally relevant to your answer)

Comment: @Tony Delroy: Apparently you somehow misunderstand the meaning of the term "unsequenced". Let's assume that it is indeed possible to deduce that somewhere inside `std::map` there's a scalar filed that stores its current size. And the above code does indeed makes multiple accesses to that field. However, these accesses are *sequenced*. Public function `std::map::size()` has sequence points (in C++03 terminology) at the beginning and at the end. That immediately means that the accesses to the internal data filed are *isolated* from each other by sequence points.

Comment: That immediately means that these accesses are *sequenced*. You must be assuming that "being sequenced" means "to occur in pre-determined pre-specified order". And since the LHS and RHS in the above code are evaluated in unspecified order, you assume that the accesses to the internal filed are *unsequenced*. That's a completely incorrect inderstanding of sequencing. "Being sequenced" means "to occur in *some* order, which is not necessarily specified". In more abstract terms "being sequenced" means "supporting the concept of *order*", regardless of whether a specific order is defined or not.

Comment: For this reason, C++11 introduces concepts of being *indeterminately sequenced*, which means that some order exists, but it is not specified which order that is. *Indeterminately sequenced* and *unsequenced* are two completely different things. In our example the LHS and RHS are *indeterminately sequenced*. Again, they are not *unsequenced*. They are *indeterminately sequenced*. And since they are not *unsequenced*, you cannot apply the rule you quoted.

Comment: @AndreyT yes I corrected the mistake earlier, but reverted since I felt it was deceiving to correct it without someone first pointing it out. I'll recorrect it now.

Comment: @Tony Delroy: In your original comment you quited "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced ... the behavior is undefined." But this rule is not applicable to our example. Unspecified evaluation order can lead to either *indeterminately sequenced* evaluation or to *unsequenced* evaluation. You need to learn to understand the difference between the two. And in this case we are dealing with *indeterminately sequenced* evaluation, again. It is *sequenced*, so there's no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @AndreyT: this boils down to "increment_x_and_return_ref() = get_x()".  C++ sequences function argument evaluation and function call (i.e. argument `0` to `map::operator[]` / no arguments to `size()`), and function return and copy/use of the returned value (i.e. both the reference to the newly inserted element and the the result of `size()` complete before `=` copies the latter to the former).  C++11 5.2.2p8: "The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the argument expressions are all *unsequenced* relative to one another." i.e. `operator[]` and `size()` have no *relative* sequencing.

Comment: @AndreyT: please note in my original quote "if a side effect...is unsequenced *relative to*... a value computation". Some sequencing within each side relative to the `=` doesn't prevent interleaved execution of inlined code from lhs and rhs in preparation for the `=`.  (See 1.9p13 "The execution of unsequenced evaluations can overlap.")

Comment: @Tony Delroy: No, that's incorrect. You keep quoting irrelevant statements. Your quote from 1.9/13 refers to immediate evaluations, not wrapped into functions. Meanwhile, the relevant statements are made in 1.9/15. It clearly states that different function calls made from the caller are *indeterminately sequenced* with relation to each other (and footnote 9 clarifies that it means that execution of function bodies cannot be interleaved). It also states that inlining has no effect on sequencing. Again: execution of functions *cannot* overlap.

Comment: In the original example both accesses to the alleged scalar `internal_size` field are wrapped into functions (`operator []` and `size()`). That immediately means that in the original expression these accesses are *indeterminately sequenced*. Not *unsequenced*, but *indeterminately sequenced*. No undefined behavior here. There was no undefined behavior here in C++03, there's no undefined behavior here in C++11.

Answer (score 7):

There are no guarantees either way unless your compiler provides guarantees. C++ standard does not.

If you need `my_map.operator [](0)` evaluated first then write:

```
int& m0 = my_map[0]; 
m0 = my_map.size();
```

If you need the `my_map.size()` evaluated first then write:

```
int s = my_map.size();
my_map[0] = s;
```

**Update:**
Since C++17 ...

```
std::map<int, int> my_map;
my_map[0] = my_map.size();
```

... will result with `my_map[0]` being `0`.

C++17 added that:

> In every simple assignment expression `E1 = E2` and every compound
> assignment expression `E1 @= E2`, every value computation and side
> effect of `E2` is sequenced before every value computation and side
> effect of `E1`.

Comment: Seems that it was good way ... or why else you edited your answer to contain about same example. ;)

Comment: +1 for good advice on how to fix it, and not having false analysis of the possible behaviours.

Answer (score 4):

Your

```
my_map[0] = my_map.size();
```

is equivalent to

```
my_map.operator [](0) = my_map.size();
```

with assignment operator being the built-in assignment for `int`.

It is unspecified which side of the built-in assignment is evaluated first. For this reason it is unspecified whether 0 or 1 will be assigned.